# Strange URLs on some php pages now a suffix a hash tag: #.UQglor99KSo

Tags: php, security, url, malware

For a couple of days, I have noticed that certain URLS on my website have gone from being called:

```
website.com/pagename.php
```

to

```
website.com/pagename.php#.UQglor99KSo
```

It is each time the exact same suffix/parameter and I cannot find a record of it anywhere in the files on the site.

The permissions on the files on the server are all 755 or higher and do not seem to have been modified recently.

Any ideas what might be behind this?  Is it a hacking attempt?

Comment: You mean, the `href` of your links now contains an additional "#xxxxx" on the end, in the source of page?

Comment: if its just in the logs, ignore it

Comment: how are the links generated? if they are just hard coded on the page, then some pages have been modified. if you are just seeing something like google linking to that page, someone probably just has a link to your site with that url.

Comment: the part of URI after # is called [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HashURI) that links to a section of the same page

Comment: @Dagon There's no way for the fragment ID to get into the logs (unless manually logged via some JavaScript). It's not part of the GET request; it's never sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason for that to appear would be the use of for example AddThis.

AddThis uses it to provide you with more detailed analytics, but you can [disable it](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/346227-is-there-a-way-to-disable-hashtags) if you want to (I always do...).

Comment: I think you might have hit the nail on the head there, address bar tracking was enalbed, I have now disabled it. Many Thanks